# Why does GPG not like this encrypted message?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I had the following encrypted message laying around on my computer from back when I was playing around with GPG (and in this case, Enigmail)

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Charset: ISO-8859-15
Version: GnuPG v2.0.20 (MingW32)
Comment: Using GnuPG with Thunderbird - http://www.enigmail.net/

.............+AWJjL0Un8xWK0lFgw26Oos
ynzsVjy9fZAVlzoVN3XgucjIG8guTrakLbbvF0aMwDIwUXb3x1b+4hGNmkx+TUQV
kE6WcnnJw5B+8/m3CQ+IxbalHKAOu7VRHZ7XJCvY6dLAIQGSmwx77S3TV4zKH5PR
p3e15GJbcM+Gfo9Ka8u6KtGZALEk9xsZjH3QmfyB66dARp4/u7gJZrJ9hd5bzXJ9
LfjEvqygdpTeak2etz+r90WbiC/P4mnXQoxz7s3m1nJESb6VcpipJFkfwFdl1BYx
0XVfY/uH/gkQGiPNQL.....................O87w==
=Cnbj
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

If I attempt to run `gpg --list-packets` or `gpg --decrypt` on the message, I get the following output (with the "invalid character skipped" warning repeated about thirty times):

```
gpg: invalid radix64 character 2E skipped
gpg: invalid radix64 character 2E skipped
gpg: invalid radix64 character 2E skipped
gpg: invalid radix64 character 2E skipped
gpg: CRC error; A3E958 - 0A76E3
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=3a)
```

Why does GPG not like this message? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4):

ASCII-armored OpenPGP messages are represented in [Radix-64 (Base64 variation with checksum added)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which doesn't have the dot symbol `.`, so obviously the data is simply corrupted.

Based on sequential repetition of the same character it is also likely the message was purposely edited to obscure it.

Comment: @jens-erat thanks for the edit, guess I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: OpenPGP.js v2.5.13
Comment: https://openpgpjs.org  , this was the problem , just remove and all will work.

Answer (score 0):

This error message could be caused by extra line breaks being added to the message after it was encrypted. I got a similar error message for this cause.

To avoid this issue for a combination of mailvelope and gmail / Google Inbox, encrypt the message as a file and attach the file. It would seem plausible that this is a work around for other scenarios.

This [blog](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/gmail-plain-text) provides a more in-depth explanation.